# kernel and cokernel of a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi: A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \to \mathbb{C}[t]=B $ be the ring morphism defined by $x\mapsto t^2, y \mapsto t^3.$ Let $f:Y=\text{Spec} B \to X=\text{Spec} A$ be the associated morphism of affine schemes.

Since $\phi$ is injective, then $f^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_X \to f_{\star}\mathcal{O}_Y$ is injective too.

> 1.What is the cokernel of $f^{\sharp}?$

I know that it will be isomorphic to the quotient sheaf $f_{\star}\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{O}_X$ but I'm unable to find it explicitly.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289491/tangent-space-exercise/291195#291195) I computed the cotangent sheaf $\Omega_X$ of $X.$

> 2.How can I find the kernel and the cokernel of $f^{\star} \Omega_X \to \Omega_Y?$

*What I've tried out*:

The sheaf morphism corresponds to a $B$-module morphism $\Omega_A \otimes_A B \to \Omega_B$ or $Adx \oplus Ady/(2ydy-3x^2dx) \otimes B \to Bdt$ which is in fact, the map $(t)dt \oplus (t^2)dt \to Bdt$ where $(tg(t)dt,t^2h(t)dt)\mapsto (tg(t)+t^2h(t))dt$ for $g,h \in B.$ The kernel is isomorphic to $B$ since $g(t)=-th(t)$ and the cokernel is $B/(t).$

**Is this correct?**

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you know that coherent sheaves over $\mathrm{Spec} A$ are equivalent to finitely generated $A$-modules.  The structure sheaf $\mathcal O_X$ corresponds to $A$ as a module over itself and $f_\ast\mathcal O_Y$ corresponds to $\mathbb C[t]$ with the $A$-module structure given by restricting through $\phi$.

So $f^\#$ corresponds to $\phi$ as a map of $A$-modules, the image of $\phi$ consists of all polynomials with no degree $1$ term so the cokernel is $(t)/(t^2)$.  The $A$-module action on this is that $x$ and $y$ act as $t^2$ and $t^3$ respectively, hence $x$ and $y$ act as $0$.  So the cokernel is a trivial $1$-dimensional $A$-module.

Edit: I forgot about $1$, the cokernel should be $1$-dimensional, not $2$.

Comment: By $(t)$ you mean the $A$-module generated by $t$ right?

Comment: By $(t)$ I meant the principal ideal generated by $t$ in $\mathbb C[t]$.

Comment: So why the cokernel is not $\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)?$

Comment: Because the unit $1 \in A$ maps to the unit $1 \in \mathbb C[t]$.  So when taking the cokernel you have to factor that out.

Comment: As a ring homomorphism $1 \mapsto 1$ not necessarily as $A$-module homomorphism, right?

Comment: That $1 \mapsto 1$ is necessarily true because it is a ring homomorphism.  There certainly exist $A$-module homomorphisms between those rings which do not satisfy that condition.

Comment: True, but the correspondence is between coherent sheaves and modules not rings and there is an $A$-module morphism $A \to B$ corresponding to $f^{\sharp},$ right?

Comment: Yes, but that $A$-module homomorphism is exactly the map $\phi$ and because $\phi$ *also* happens to be a ring homomorphism we know that it sends $1 \mapsto 1$.

Comment: Dear @Jim, now I see. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Jim, just to make sure, could you check my computation for the second question?